# Folder named "1" in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-library, content-migration

After migrating the SharePoint 2010 site to O365, some of the libraries have this folder named "1" at the top level. All content is inside this folder. That folder was there in 2010 site but it was not visible there. This is may be due to some series event feature.

How to overcome this issue in O365. I can not move contents from "1" named folder because it will affect the links given in the site. 
Is there any option other than using a filter on folder name to hide this folder ? How to enable this series event feature  in o365?.

Answer (score 0):

Any funny issues and restructuring of the content ( like splitting folders into doclibs to prevent the dreaded 5000 docs limit) should happen now, as part of the migration. The end users will to some extend understand that it is part of the game. Better now then in 3 months time.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, You can modify the current view and select “Show all items without folders” under Folders section as: below:
[image]

Comment: Showing items without folders is not an option because there are some other folders which i dont want to hide.